# Understanding memory allotment in heap

Tags: c, memory-management, heap-memory

I was trying to understand how memory is allotted on the heap using malloc, and came across the following observation, and am unable to understand the reason behind it. It would be great if someone can explain.

First, let's take a look at the code I wrote:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void print_int_heap(unsigned int *ptr, int len)
{
    printf("PREV_SIZE: [%08x]  SIZE: [%08x]  MEM: [%08x] for INT malloc(%d)\n", *(ptr-2), *(ptr-1), ptr, len);
}
void print_char_heap(char *ptr, int len)
{
    printf("PREV_SIZE: [%08x]  SIZE: [%08x]  MEM: [%08x] for CHAR malloc(%d)\n", *(ptr-2), *(ptr-1), ptr, len);
}

int main() {

    unsigned int *ptr1 = malloc(20);
    print_int_heap(ptr1, 20);
    char *ptr2 = malloc(20)
    print_char_heap(ptr2, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

The output which I get for the above program is:

```
PREV_SIZE: [0x00000000] SIZE: [0x00000019] MEM: [0x0804b008] for INT malloc(20)
PREV_SIZE: [0x00000000] SIZE: [0x00000000] MEM: [0x0804b020] for INT malloc(20)
```

I can understand the output for the int malloc, but I do not understand why the value for size of chunk for char malloc is 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ptr` is an `int*`, `*(ptr - 1)` refers to the `sizeof(int)` bytes just before what `ptr` references. That will ususlly be a 32-bit quantity starting four bytes before `ptr`.

Similarly, if it is a `char*`, `*(ptr - 1)` refers to the `sizeof(char)` bytes just before what `ptr` references. `sizeof(char)` is always 1; normally that will be the 8-bit quantity in the single byte preceding the value of `ptr`.

These are obviously quite different things.

By the way, you are allowed to write `ptr[-1]`. But as the above analysis show, that's really not what you want. You want to cast `ptr` to a pointer to the datatype of the object(s) you believe precede `ptr`, probably `uint32_t`.

Technically this is all Undefined Behaviour, but if your `malloc` implementation is stashing data just before the allocation and you know the type of that data, I'd say that it's fine to read it. (Although it's always a bit rude to stare at the internal data of a system function.)

Be aware that not all `malloc` implementations do the same thing. You may well find one which storrs the length elsewhere or not at all.

Answer (score 1):

From **C programming language** book by **DENNIS M. RITCHIE**

> Rather than allocating from a compiled-in **fixed-sized** array,
>   **malloc** will request space from the operating system as needed. Since other activities in the program may also request space without
>   calling this allocator, the space that
>   **malloc** manages may not be contiguous. Thus its free storage is kept as a list of **free blocks**. Each block contains a **size**, a
>   **pointer to the next block**, and the
>   **space itself**. The blocks are kept in order of increasing storage address, and the last block (highest address) points to the first. The
>   block returned by malloc() looks like
>
> ```
>     points to          
>     next free
>      block       
>       |                
>    ---------------------------------------
>    |       |   size   |                  |
>    ---------------------------------------
>    |       |          |..address returned to the user
>    (ptr-2) (ptr-1)    ptr -->     
>                       LSB              MSB
> ```
>
> Here

```
void print_int_heap(unsigned int *ptr, int len) {
    printf("PREV_SIZE: [%08x]  SIZE: [%08x]  MEM: [%08x] for INT malloc(%d)\n", *(ptr-2), *(ptr-1), ptr, len);
}
```

`*(ptr-2)` prints the value inside  `"next free block"` as shown in above image and `*(ptr-1)` prints the value inside `"size"` block i.e how much memory allocated, & `ptr` prints the address returned by user. Note that here `ptr` type is `unsigned int*` so `*(ptr-2)` means accessing data from `2*sizeof(int)` bytes just before where `ptr` points.

And here

```
void print_char_heap(char *ptr, int len){
    printf("PREV_SIZE: [%08x]  SIZE: [%08x]  MEM: [%08x] for CHAR malloc(%d)\n", *(ptr-2), *(ptr-1), ptr, len);
}
```

while accessing `*(ptr-1)`

> ```
>     next free
>      block        (ptr-1)--> *(ptr-1) prints data from ? marked location.
>       |            |  
>    ---------------------------------------
>    |       | size |? |                  |
>    ---------------------------------------
>    |       |         |..address returned to the user
>                      ptr -->     
>                      LSB              MSB
> ```

`ptr` type is `char*` means when you do `*(ptr-1)` it will access data from `sizeof(char)` bytes just before where `ptr` points.

Also better to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual.html) when memory allocated dynamically & make sure there is no where memory leakage happens, simply by running

```
valgrind --leak-check=full -v ./your_exe
```

and analyzing the messages of `valgrind`. for e.g it may show something like

```
==3193== Invalid read of size 4
==3193==    at 0x8048459: print_int_heap
==3193== Invalid read of size 4
==3193==    at 0x8048461: print_int_heap
```

Comment: He's clearly trying to access the implementation-dependent bookkeeping data of malloc. The fact that it's UB is probably irrelevant, just like in questions about shellcode exploits.

Comment: Yes. How I forget that ?. Thanks @Barmar let me modify.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform arithmetic on a pointer, the arithmetic is done in units of the size of the object that the pointer points to. So with `char *ptr`, `ptr-1` subtracts 1 byte from the address in `ptr`. But with `unsigned int *ptr`, `ptr-1` subtracts `sizeof(int)` from the address in `ptr`.

So in your two functions, you're not subtracting the same number of bytes to get to the heap's bookkeeping data for the block.

Also, when you dereference a pointer, it only accesses the number of bytes in the pointer's data type. So in `print_int_heap()`, `*(ptr-1)` returns an `unsigned int`, while in `print_char_heap()` it returns a single `char`.

You should probably just write a single `print_heap()` function, and cast the argument to the appropriate type in the caller.